# Array outof bound Mapreduce

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop

Im trying to run sort algorithm using mapreduce but always i recieve  Array out ofBound

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at to.SecSortMapper.map(SecSortMapper.java:17)
at to.SecSortMapper.map(SecSortMapper.java:1)
```

**Code**

```
if (value.toString().length() > 0) {
    String arrEmpAttributes[] = value.toString().split("\\t");
    context.write(new TextPair(arrEmpAttributes[6].toString(),
            (arrEmpAttributes[3].toString() + "\t" + arrEmpAttributes[2].toString() + "\t" + arrEmpAttributes[0].toString())), nullWritable.get());

}
```

> Line 17 is new TextPair(.............)

i tried to change value string length >1 but it doesnt work  can anyone help please?

Comment: You should also create one more check `if (arrEmpAttributes.length >0)`
because you are using  arrEmpAttributes[6] may be its length less than 6

Comment: if (value.toString().length() > 1) {
String arrEmpAttributes[] = value.toString().split("\\t");
//System.out.printf("longeuur est",arrEmpAttributes.length);
context.write(
new TextPair(arrEmpAttributes[6].toString(),
(arrEmpAttributes[3].toString() + "\t"
+ arrEmpAttributes[2].toString() + "\t" + arrEmpAttributes[0].toString())),
NullWritable.null
}}
here is peusdocode i think its useless to create another if (aarrEmAttribute>0}

Comment: sorry if(arrEmpAttributes.length> 6)

Answer (score 0):

You're making the assumption that `arrEmpAttributes` contains at least 7 elements, none of which are `null`. This is a risky assumption to make, especially in the big data world where you're almost guaranteed to be dealing with some inconsistencies in your input data.

Your `if` statement should look like the following:

```
valueStr = value.toString(); //Declare this outside of the loop for efficiency
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(valueStr)) {
    arrEmpAttributes[] = valueStr.split(TAB_SEPARATOR); //Also declare these two outside of the loop
    if(!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(arrEmpAttributes) && arrEmpAttributes.length==SEVEN) {
    //context.write...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i changed my code this way and i have no more error but i got 7 output empty file
    String valueStr = value.toString();
 if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(valueStr)) {</br>
  String arrEmpAttributes[] = valueStr.split("\\t"); </br>
     if(!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(arrEmpAttributes) && arrEmpAttributes.length==7) { </br>
      context.write( </br>
        new TextPair(arrEmpAttributes[6].toString(), </br>
        (arrEmpAttributes[3].toString() + "\t"  </br>
        + arrEmpAttributes[2].toString() + "\t" +   </br> arrEmpAttributes[0].toString())),  </br>
        NullWritable.get());
     }
 }
 }

Comment: how can i fix this please? and how can i format code when i write here

Comment: You can't format code in comments other than by adding backticks. If you're getting empty output files then your input must never turn into seven elements. Write a unit test to test this logic, and use a small sample of your actual input. That should help you, and be much quicker to debug.

Comment: I have only 1 input file i need to sort it with specific character can you help me please to fix and achieve that ?

Comment: Even when i tried this code doesnt work http://hadooped.blogspot.com/2013/09/sample-code-for-secondary-sort.html same probleme out of bond and when i try to fix code with your solution it work but always different number (7--10) output blank file
 String valueStr = value.toString(); 
 if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(valueStr)) {
  String arrEmpAttributes[] = valueStr.split("\\t"); 
     if(!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(arrEmpAttributes) && arrEmpAttributes.length==6) {
      context.write(
        new CompositeKeyWritable(arrEmpAttributes[6].toString(),
        (arrEmpAttributes[3].toString() + "\t"...

Comment: MRUnit is good, or you could extract your actual logic (i.e. the code inside of the reducer) into a different method and test that, feeding it actual lines of input and seeing what comes out.

Comment: thanks bro :)) it's my 1st time ill use Unit test and i don't know how it work, there is another method to fix that or if you have source code sort it work ? i really stuck on this in my study for 4month :/ i have dataset i wanna sort it